# The expected value of a fractional part of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim N(\mu, 1)$ where it is known that $ \mu$ Is an integer.

Define an estimator $\delta$ by taking the sample mean and rounding it to the nearest integer.

My aim is to show that given the restricted parameter space, the estimator is unbiased.

My attempt:

By expressing the random variable in terms of indicator functions floors and fractional parts, we can write the expected value of $\delta $ as

$$E \delta = E floor(X_n) + P(fractional (X_n) >0.5)$$

Hence if I can show that

$$ E fractional(X_n) = P(fractional (X_n) >0.5)$$ then the result follows. Intuitively I think this makes sense, but I’m not sure how to proceed further. So far I have not used the fact the parameter space is restricted, but I think it must play a role in the proof some how

Comment: I recommend going on [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some formatting tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $\{x\}$ to represent the fractional part of $x$

Given the value of $\mu$, we can let $Y=X -\mu$.  We then have:

- $Y \sim N(0,1)$ since we have subtracted the mean of $X$
- $E[\{Y\}] = E[\{X\}]$ and $P\left(\{Y\} > \frac12\right) = P\left(\{X\} > \frac12\right)$ since we have subtracted an integer
- $P\left(\{Y\} > \frac12 \mid Y >0\right)=P\left(\{Y\} \le \frac12 \mid Y \le 0\right)$ and  $P\left(\{Y\} \le  \frac12 \mid Y >0\right)=P\left(\{Y\} \gt \frac12 \mid Y \le 0\right)$ by symmetry of the standard normal
- $P\left(\{Y\} > \frac12\right) = \frac12P(\{Y\} > \frac12 \mid Y >0) +\frac12P(\{Y\} > \frac12 \mid Y \le 0) \\ = \frac12P(\{Y\} > \frac12 \mid Y >0) +\frac12P(\{Y\} \le \frac12 \mid Y > 0) = \frac12$
- $E[\{Y\} \mid Y >0] = E[1-\{Y\} \mid Y \le 0] $ so $E[\{Y\} \mid Y >0] + E[\{Y\} \mid Y \le 0]=1$
- $E[\{Y\}] = \frac12E[\{Y\} \mid Y >0] + \frac12E[\{Y\} \mid Y \le 0] =\frac12$

and this leads to $E[\{X\}]=\frac12= P\left(\{X\} > \frac12\right)$ for given $\mu$ and so for all $\mu$ as requested

Similar manipulations lead to seeing that $\{Y\}$ and $\{X\}$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$

There may be another approach: by symmetry, for given $\mu$ the expectation of the rounded value of $Y$ is $0$ and so the expectation of the rounded value of $X$ is $\mu$, meaning that the rounded value of $X$ (or the sample mean of several independent observations of it) is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although the second method is a lot simpler, actually it prefer the first as it has helped me to better make use of symmetry about zero in these sorts of problems. Thanks for taking the time to explain it in full